# Collecting data as a tuple using Selenium Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I have a trouble collecting data as tuple using Selenium Python 3.6. This is the page I would like to collect data (http://www.bobaedream.co.kr/cyber/CyberCar.php?gubun=I) 
I would like to collect the "manufacturer (maker)" data in the search menu at the upper part of the page.

[image]

I used selenium webdrivet to set the virtual page and use this code to collect and the select the list of the first drop-down menu:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep


link = 'http://www.bobaedream.co.kr/cyber/CyberCar.php?gubun=I'
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
driver.get(link)
sleep(.75)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser", from_encoding='utf-8')

manufacturers = [
    ('%s', '%s') % (o.text, o.get_attribute('href'))
    for o
    in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#layer_maker ul.list li a")
    if o.text != '전체']

for manufacturer in manufacturers:
    driver.execute_script("o.get_attribute('href')")
```

And, this is the error message that I had:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 /Users/chongwonshin/PycharmProjects/Crawler_test/dump.py
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py:146: UserWarning: You provided Unicode markup but also provided a value for from_encoding. Your from_encoding will be ignored.
  warnings.warn("You provided Unicode markup but also provided a value for from_encoding. Your from_encoding will be ignored.")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/chongwonshin/PycharmProjects/Crawler_test/dump.py", line 23, in <module>
    in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#layer_maker ul.list li a")
  File "/Users/chongwonshin/PycharmProjects/Crawler_test/dump.py", line 24, in <listcomp>
    if o.text != '전체']
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'tuple' and 'tuple'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you need:

```
[
('%s' % o.text, '%s' % o.get_attribute('href'))
for o
in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#layer_maker ul.list li a")
if o.text != '전체']
```

or just

```
[
(o.text, o.get_attribute('href'))
for o
in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#layer_maker ul.list li a")
if o.text != '전체']
```

Note that `%` is also a "modulo" operator in `Python` that you cannot apply to tuples